# Kotlin and verbose array instantiation

Tags: arrays, syntax, kotlin

Let say that I have path that goes through 4 vertices. When doing rapid prototyping I would define this in java as

```
double[][] path = {{1.0, 2.0}, {1.0,3.0}, {3.0,4.0}, {8.0,9.0}}
```

Using the arrayOf, and doubleArrayOf function the same code in Kotlin would be

```
val path = arrayOf(doubleArrayOf(1.0, 2.0), doubleArrayOf(1.0, 2.0), doubleArrayOf(1.0,3.0), doubleArrayOf(8.0,9.0))
```

Which feels a bit verbose. Is there a Kotlin way of solving this ?

*Edit:* The use-case is answering queries in a "REPL like" environment on numerical data i.e. think Matlab or SciPy.

Comment: I would write "normal" production Kotlin code with `data` classes and archive the speed and ease of "rapid prototyping". Not sure about the REPL thing..

Comment: What does the "REPL like" environment mean in terms of the question, it isn't clear how that impacts possible answers.

Comment: Meant as in a scientific workflow dealing with shorter code snippets, usually but not exclusively done in a REPL. Basically based on a hunch you form a hypothesis and a set of question to test the hypothesis. To try your question you mock-up some trivial test data. You iterate a couple of times over real and test data. The problem is programmatically trivial, instead the domain is a challenge. In the end the hypothesis is usually discarded and you move on. If you strike gold then you build a service using regular software methodologies.

Comment: If I need this often I would use a little language: `val path = a("{1.0, 2.0}, {1.0,3.0}, {3.0,4.0}, {8.0,9.0}")`. I think this is something to fix in the language, not with custom code, I arrived here looking for numpy like syntax...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arrayOf` and `doubleArrayOf` and others like them, are just top level functions in stdlib.  To shorten the syntax, you can easily create your own functions with [scope](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#function-scope) at the top level, within a class, or even locally within a function:

By creating:

```
fun pathOf(vararg points: DoubleArray): Array<out DoubleArray> = points
fun pt(x: Double, y: Double) = doubleArrayOf(x,y)
```

This allows:

```
val path = pathOf(pt(1.0, 2.0), pt(1.0, 2.0), pt(1.0, 3.0), pt(8.0, 9.0))
```

Which now gives the nested arrays meaning for a future reader or the code.  Name the function `point`, `pt`, `xy`, or whatever suits your use case.

This code is only slightly longer than the original, and maybe more readable/meaningful than the Java:

```
double[][] path = {{1.0, 2.0}, {1.0, 3.0}, {3.0, 4.0}, {8.0, 9.0}}
```

These functions are just as efficient as using `arrayOf` and `doubleArrayOf` and if used repeatedly the JVM will eventually `inline` them, but if you are nervous you can make them `inline` yourself.

*Kotlin is intended to be extended*, any time you run into an issue like this think about how you can extend an API or change a function to get the readability you desire.

Comment: This is the obvious answer. The use-case is answering queries in a "REPL like" environment on numerical big data i.e. think Matlab or numpy. The current solution I use is to setup generic short-hand functions for array creation such as `fun d(vararg v: Double) = doubleArrayOf(*v)` and   `fun f(vararg v: Float) = floatArrayOf(*v) ` . Sometime I get a feeling that what Kotlin gives in with one hand i.e. operator overloading and infix it takes aways with the other i.e array declaration. Many thanks for the input!

Comment: Clarification to comment above. I'm not really happy with the need of declaring a generic short-hand function for array declaration just to make snippets of code readable. So are there better options or is this the way to go ?

Comment: This is it for arrays.  Kotlin doesn't want them special cased differently than other collection types.  Arrays actually have a statistically low usage in the JVM world, and a large bit of those are accidental when people should be using normal collections.  So they are placed at the same discovery level and syntax level as collections to even the field.

Comment: You could create operator + for a `Pair<Double, Double>` and create a `pt(): Pair<Double, Double>` function for creating it, override the plus operator, and then chain a bunch of adds to make an array.  But it is just a remix of the same.

Answer (score 10):

As far as the stdlib goest, this is as short as it gets. You could however define a helper function yourself:

```
fun doubles(vararg values: Pair<Double, Double>) = values
    .map { doubleArrayOf(it.first, it.second) }
    .toTypedArray()
```

Usage:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val path = doubles(1.0 to 2.0, 1.0 to 3.0, 3.0 to 4.0, 8.0 to 9.0)
}
```

This is not the most efficient solution because it involves boxing and allocation of one temporary array and list, but if you're only prototyping this should be ok.

EDIT:

I also made a version where you can add arrays of arbitrary length:

```
inline fun doubles(block: DoubleArrayBuilder.() -> Unit) = DoubleArrayBuilder()
        .apply(block)
        .list.toTypedArray()

class DoubleArrayBuilder {
    val list = mutableListOf<DoubleArray>()

    fun add(vararg doubles: Double) = list.add(doubles)
}
```

Usage:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val path = doubles {
        add(2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
        add(2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
        add(2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Performance is not a biggie but readability is. A limitation I see with your setup is that it is limited to Pairs.

Comment: I edited my answer and added a builder-style version where you can add double arrays of arbitrary length.